# How do I trigger the manipulation of the DOM after a partial view is loaded in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I trigger the manipulation of the DOM after a partial view is loaded in AngularJS?

If I were using jQuery, I could do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // do stuff here
}
```

But in Angular, in particular with partial views, how would I do such? As a more concrete example, I have the following basic non-interactive Angular app (html and js on the same page source):

http://cssquirrel.com/testcases/ang-demo/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Angular Question</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

        var controller = {
            demoController: function ($scope, demoFactory) {
                $scope.fruits = demoFactory.getFruits();
            }
        };

        var factory = {
            demoFactory: function () {
                var fruits = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cherries'];
                var factory = {
                    getFruits: function () {
                        return fruits;
                    }
                };
                return factory;
            }
        }

        function appRoute($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/step-1',
                    {
                        controller: 'demoController',
                        templateUrl: 'partial.html'
                    })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/step-1' });
        };


        app.config(appRoute);
        app.factory(factory);
        app.controller(controller);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which has the following partial:

http://cssquirrel.com/testcases/ang-demo/partial.html

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{fruit}}</li>
</ul>
```

So, if in this basic app, I wanted to add a class "active" to the first list item in the list after the partial view has finished loading, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stop thinking in terms of DOM manipulation. It's not the first LI that's active, rather it's the first fruit that has been selected.

First up, support the concept of a fruit being selected

```
var fruits = [
  { name: 'apples', active: true },
  { name: 'bananas', active: false },
  { name: 'cherries', active: false }
]
```

Then, support that attribute with an ng-class in your angular template:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-class="{ active: fruit.active }">{{fruit.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now you can manipulate your fruits array and change which one is selected, for example:

```
$scope.fruits[2].active = true;
```

Comment: I've got some questions on how I would then dynamically change the selected active fruit afterwards (say, if I clicked on it), but this pretty accurately answers the example given.

Comment: @KyleWeems After the fact you would change the values in the array, and let angular handle updating the DOM. When it comes to array manipulation, I personally use underscore in tandem with angular, since it has excellent filtering and manipulation functions for arrays.

Comment: I'll check Underscore out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is model driven. If you want to change DOM, then change data instead.

You can use `$first` property to activate the first item of the repeater.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{active : $first}" data-ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{fruit}}</li>
</ul>
```

Or if you want to manually activate any item of the repeater by clicking on it, you can change the activate field of the model object.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{true: 'active', false: ''}[fruit.active]" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-click="activate(fruit)">{{fruit.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Use this data structure

```
var factory = {
    demoFactory: function () {
        var fruits = [{
            name: 'apples',
            active: true
        }, {
            name: 'bananas',
            active: false
        }, {
            name: 'cherries',
            active: false
        }]
        var factory = {
            getFruits: function () {
                return fruits;
            }
        };
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And add this in the controller.

```
$scope.activate = function (fruit) {
    console.log(fruit)
    fruit.active = true;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ShcCv)**</kbd>

Comment: This is useful in directly helping with the example I put together, but doesn't answer the overall question.

Comment: I am the OP. It addresses the list-item example, but doesn't discuss how to trigger post-load DOM manipulation, which is the overall question.

Comment: @KyleWeems If you can create a jsfiddle, then I can give you a correct answer of the other question you have. Btw, what is your question? Manipulate DOM of what?

Comment: @KyleWeems And what do you want to achieve? Why other guys think you need a flag to indicate active or not but in your question you need just the first item of the row to be activated? What is you question again?

Comment: I was trying to state a very simple example. Let's go with that as a starting point: I have a list of fruit. By default I want the first one to be active when the page loads. Then I want whichever one I click to become active instead. How would I do this with AngularJS?

Answer (score -2):

You would set an active property on that model and check for adding it to every element.

```
var controller = {
    demoController: function ($scope, demoFactory) {
        $scope.fruits = demoFactory.getFruits();
        $scope.fruits[0].isActive = true; // kinda hacky
    }
};

<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-class="{ active: fruit.isActive }}">{{fruit}}</li>
</ul>
```

This isn't exactly how I would do it, but with angular it is **always** best to edit the model so that you maintain 1 single definitive representation of the state of your application.